# Similarly Ordered

Tags: nt.number-theory

A theorem of Erdos states:

"There exists an absolute constant c such that, if n>ck, and if a<sub>1</sub>/b<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>/b<sub>2</sub>, ... are the Farey fractions of order n, then a<sub>x</sub>/b<sub>x</sub> and a<sub>x+k</sub>/b<sub>x+k</sub> are similarly ordered."

Can someone provide a definition of "similarly ordered" as used here?

Thanks for any insight.

Cheers, Scott

@ARTICLE{Erdos:1943,
  author={Erd{\"o}s, Paul},
  title={A note on {F}arey series},
  journal={Quart. J. Math., Oxford Ser.},
  fjournal={The Quarterly Journal of Mathematics. Oxford. Second Series},
  volume={14},
  year={1943},
  pages={82--85},
  issn={0033-5606},
  mrclass={40.0X},
  mrnumber={MR0009999 (5,236b)},
  mrreviewer={G. Szeg{\"o}}

Comment: A comment, not an answer: I assume that $a_{x+k}b_{x+k}$ is a typo for $a_{x+k}/b_{x+k}$. Can you give us the reference for the paper so we can have a look at the context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a link that gives the definition: http://qjmath.oxfordjournals.org/cgi/pdf_extract/os-13/1/185

It's to the paper by Mayer that Erdos refers to. (The link gives you just the first page of the paper, but fortunately the definition is on that page.)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it means that for any $x,y$, we have $a_x/b_x < a_y/b_y$ iff $a_{x+k}b_{x+k} < a_{y+k}b_{y+k}$.

Edit: On second thought, this seems unlikely, because with the definition I gave the theorem doesn't make sense for $k=1$, $n > 5$: we have $a_1/b_1 = 1/n, a_2/b_2 = 1/(n-1), a_3/b_3 = 1/(n-2)$, and $a_1/b_1 < a_2/b_2$ but $a_2b_2 > a_3b_3$. Maybe it means that for more than half of all pairs the order will be the same?